# How to remove maplabel library and polygon in Google Map API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, label, drawing, polygon

I'm using google maps API to allow the user draw polygons and display the length of every single border using `maplabel library`. But I have a problem when removing `polygon` and `map label`, I don't know how to remove them from Google Map.

My code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="enablePolygon">draw</button>
<button id="removePolygon">remove</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-map-label@1.0.1/src/maplabel.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
var labels = [];
var allOverlays = [];

function setSelection(shape) {
  selectedShape = shape;
  shape.setEditable(true);
}

function initMap() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 52.250618,
      lng: 20.9774
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    polygonOptions: {
      draggable: false,
      fillColor: "#0e97fa",
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: "#0e97fa",
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    },
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: 
      [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                /* google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE, */
      ]
    },
    map: map,
    drawingMode: 'polygon'
  });

  
  function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon) {
    if (!polygon.labels) polygon.labels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.labels.length; i++) {
      polygon.labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
    polygon.labels = [];
    var path = polygon.getPath();
    var points = path.getArray();
    var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical
      .computeArea(path.getArray())
      .toFixed(0);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(points[i]);
    }

    var boundsCenter = bounds.getCenter();
    var centerLabel = new MapLabel({
      map: map,
      position: boundsCenter,
      fontSize: 14,
      align: "center",
      zIndex: 3
    });
    polygon.labels.push(centerLabel);

    centerLabel.set("position", bounds.getCenter());
    centerLabel.set("text", area + " m2");
    if (path.getLength() < 2) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      // for each side in path, compute center and length
      var start = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
      var end = polygon.getPath().getAt(i < polygon.getPath().getLength() - 1 ? i + 1 : 0);
      var sideLength = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, end);
      console.log(sideLength)
      var sideCenter = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, end, 0.5);
     /*  console.log("sideCenter=" + sideCenter.toUrlValue(6)); */
      var sideLabel = new MapLabel({
        map: map,
        fontSize: 14,
        align: "center",
        zIndex: 3
      });
      sideLabel.set("position", sideCenter);
      sideLabel.set("text", sideLength.toFixed(2) + "m");
      polygon.labels.push(sideLabel);
    }
  }

  function removePolygonInfoWindow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
    labels = [];
  }

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(e) {
    allOverlays.push(e);

    if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

      var newShape = e.overlay;
      newShape.type = e.type;

      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, "click", function() {
        setSelection(newShape);
      });

      if (newShape.type == "polygon") {
        var path = newShape.getPath();

        google.maps.event.addListener(path, "insert_at", function() {
          attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(path, "set_at", function() {
          attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
        });

        attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
      }

      setSelection(newShape);
    }
  });

 var enablePolygon = document.getElementById('enablePolygon');
 enablePolygon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
  });

 var removePolygon = document.getElementById('removePolygon');
 removePolygon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
      drawingManager.setMap(null);
      centerLabel.setRemoveLabel(true);
  });
}

initMap();
```

[Here is demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t90nw5sq/1/)

Comment: JSFiddle site was down for a few hours yesterday. You got an answer now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: centerLabel is not defined`.  Not sure why you are using that variable, you are saving the labels in a property of the polygons `labels`.  To remove them, iterate through that array, calling `.setMap(null)` on each label.

```
  removePolygon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
    drawingManager.setMap(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedShape.labels.length; i++) {
      selectedShape.labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
  });
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/41ynhsm6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var labels = [];
var allOverlays = [];

function setSelection(shape) {
  selectedShape = shape;
  shape.setEditable(true);
}

function initMap() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
      lat: 52.250618,
      lng: 20.9774
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    polygonOptions: {
      draggable: false,
      fillColor: "#0e97fa",
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: "#0e97fa",
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    },
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        /* google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE, */
      ]
    },
    map: map,
    drawingMode: 'polygon'
  });


  function attachPolygonInfoWindow(polygon) {
    if (!polygon.labels) polygon.labels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.labels.length; i++) {
      polygon.labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
    polygon.labels = [];
    var path = polygon.getPath();
    var points = path.getArray();
    var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical
      .computeArea(path.getArray())
      .toFixed(0);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(points[i]);
    }

    var boundsCenter = bounds.getCenter();
    var centerLabel = new MapLabel({
      map: map,
      position: boundsCenter,
      fontSize: 14,
      align: "center",
      zIndex: 3
    });
    polygon.labels.push(centerLabel);

    centerLabel.set("position", bounds.getCenter());
    centerLabel.set("text", area + " m2");
    if (path.getLength() < 2) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      // for each side in path, compute center and length
      var start = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
      var end = polygon.getPath().getAt(i < polygon.getPath().getLength() - 1 ? i + 1 : 0);
      var sideLength = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, end);
      console.log(sideLength)
      var sideCenter = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(start, end, 0.5);
      /*  console.log("sideCenter=" + sideCenter.toUrlValue(6)); */
      var sideLabel = new MapLabel({
        map: map,
        fontSize: 14,
        align: "center",
        zIndex: 3
      });
      sideLabel.set("position", sideCenter);
      sideLabel.set("text", sideLength.toFixed(2) + "m");
      polygon.labels.push(sideLabel);
    }
  }

  function removePolygonInfoWindow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
    labels = [];
  }

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function(e) {
    allOverlays.push(e);

    if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

      var newShape = e.overlay;
      newShape.type = e.type;

      google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, "click", function() {
        setSelection(newShape);
      });

      if (newShape.type == "polygon") {
        var path = newShape.getPath();

        google.maps.event.addListener(path, "insert_at", function() {
          attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(path, "set_at", function() {
          attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
        });

        attachPolygonInfoWindow(newShape);
      }

      setSelection(newShape);
    }
  });

  var enablePolygon = document.getElementById('enablePolygon');
  enablePolygon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON);
  });
  var removePolygon = document.getElementById('resetPolygon');
  removePolygon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
    drawingManager.setMap(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedShape.labels.length; i++) {
      selectedShape.labels[i].setMap(null);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="enablePolygon">draw</button>
<button id="resetPolygon">remove</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=drawing"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-map-label@1.0.1/src/maplabel.js"></script>
```